# UPDATE column with its maximum for each row in oracle without PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I want to update a column of a table in a ORACLE/DB. I have a column that contains a `code = 0` and I want it to be replaced by the maximum value of this column. Every row with a 0 needs to change and to have the new maximum value of the column from table.
I'll just do it once that's why I don't need PL/SQL.

for example if i have

```
CLIENT CODE

 JOJO 99
 JUJU 0
 JAJA 0
```

I want it to become

```
CLIENT CODE
  JOJO 99
  JUJU 100
  JAJA 101
```

If i do

```
update CLIENT set CODE = (select MAX(CODE) from CLIENT)+1 WHERE CODE = 0;
```

Unfortunately the command put (let's say my maximum is 99) the value 100 in all my row with a `code = 0`
I'd want that every row with `code = 0` as an unique value that increases

Can you please help me with that

Comment: CODE starts with 0 ? can u use a sequence?  `update CLIENT set CODE = MYSEQ.NEXTVAL WHERE CODE = 0`

Comment: I guess it's a good temporary solution. The thing is that the code is a varchar on 3 char. I can create a sequence that begins with 100 and update my rows with it The "sequence" is handled in a tcl code (which is totally a dirty). I guess i'll just correct it that way and then ask for an evolution of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use rownum instead of 1:

```
update CLIENT set CODE = (select MAX(CODE) from CLIENT)+ROWNUM WHERE CODE = 0;
```

Comment: this one works perfectly, I didn't know rownum could be used like that, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try this, this might work for you:

```
UPDATE table_name
set t.CODE=(SELECT max(Code)+1 from table_name t)
WHERE CODE=0;
```

I am not sure.